# Sql data reader wont return my values to objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I have this code that gets the return query from SQL and place it in Labels. The problem is, when I click the Search Button, The Labels wont populate. but when I enter debug mode, It has values. Why is that?! help!

```
//I've cut down the code here to make the question clearer
//But these 4 fields were all valid properties - Sayse
public string FirstName
public string MiddleName
public string LastName
public string Email

  public void SearchAffectedUser()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {

            using (SqlCommand com_retrieve = new SqlCommand("Reader.usp_SearchAffectedUser", con))
            {
                com_retrieve.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com_retrieve.Parameters.Add("@fld_EmployeeId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = AffectedUser;
                con.Open();

                com_retrieve.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataReader dr = com_retrieve.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.Read())
                {

                    FirstName = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    MiddleName = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    LastName = dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
                    Email = dr.GetValue(3).ToString();
                }

            }
        }
    }

  protected void findAffectedUserButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ticket.AffectedUser = affectedUserTextBox.Text;
        ticket.FirstName = firstNameValueLabel.Text;
        ticket.MiddleName = middleNameValueLabel.Text;
        ticket.LastName = lastNameValueLabel.Text;
        ticket.Email = emailValueLabel.Text;
        ticket.SearchAffectedUser();

    }
```

Comment: Where do you set text for the labels?

Comment: in my web page button_click

Comment: I've edited your code to remove some of the property declarations as it was just spamming your question's code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First set the AffectedUser property used for the search then call the search command and finally set the labels.

```
protected void findAffectedUserButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ticket.AffectedUser = affectedUserTextBox.Text;
    ticket.SearchAffectedUser();
    firstNameValueLabel.Text = ticket.FirstName;
    middleNameValueLabel.Text = ticket.MiddleName;
    lastNameValueLabel.Text = ticket.LastName;
    emailValueLabel.Text = ticket.Email;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

set label *TEXT* property to "".